# Limit Form Submission For User Per Page

Tags: php, forms, joomla

Although the following code comes from RSForm, the tool I'm currently using for my forms, I believe my question may be solved with pure PHP knowledge, although my struggle isn't getting anywhere from here.

Is there any way to limit the user to answer the form a specific number of times in specific pages where my form shows?

I have the same form being recycled in many pages and I wish the users could answer only once per page. Is that possible at all?

I got this code that already successfully limits the number of times I wish each user to be able to submit the form, but how do I only limit them if they answer the form in specific pages? The result I wish is that they may answer the same form only once per page where they find the form.

```
// Define the maximum number of submissions.
$max = 1;

// Get the current logged in user.
$user = JFactory::getUser();

// Get a database connection.
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$query   = $db->getQuery(true);

// Setup the query.
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').')')
    ->from($db->qn('#__rsform_submissions'))
    ->where($db->qn('FormId').'='.$db->q($formId))
    ->where($db->qn('Username').'='.$db->q($user->get('username')));
    // You can also count by User ID, just replace the above with:
    // ->where($db->qn('UserId').'='.$db->q($user->get('id')));

$db->setQuery($query);
$counter = $db->loadResult();

if ($counter >= $max){
  $formLayout = 'Sorry, you have reached the maximum number of submissions for this form.';
}
```

Is there anyway to adapt this to limit only if the form is submitted at the same page?

---

**EDIT:**

These forms will always be on K2 Item pages and I figured that I can get the item ID with this code:

```
$K2Itemid = JRequest::getInt('id');
```

I think I can use this as the condition that I'm missing. I could limit the submission with the K2 ID as a different page. May someone help me apply this? How would I insert this condition?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some of the PHP server variables.

I would make a hidden field in the form and set it to log **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** as a value in the submission itself. If you have query strings you may need to use **$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']** as well.

In your code set a variable there and use it as in your WHERE for your query to return submissions where from that URL.

Comment: I edited my post to show that as I'm using K2 Item, maybe that could be used in the script to limit the submission. Do you think you may help me apply that information in the "where". I'm sorry but I'm a beginner with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could include IP as a field in the database, then after the user submits the form check on the server side if that IP already submitted anything. Save the date of the submission and wipe every submission older than a day.